Blazor Server: Fix "Could not reconnect to the server" problem
I've developed an application in .NET 8 Blazor Server (deployed to Azure with a SignalR service). The user often starts to enter some info (often, quite a lot of info) in a form, gets pulled onto some other issue and then comes back to find the server has disconnected; the screen is grayed and the message at the top of the screen is: "Could not reconnect to the server. Reload the page to restore functionality". The time it takes for this disconnection seems random.
The client would like to have the connection remain active for at least 2 hours from the last UI activity. I have tried:

Chrome, Settings, Performance, Memory Saver: OFF
Chrome, Settings, Performance: Adding the site to "Always keep these sites active"
Program.cs: builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor: set DisconnectedCircuitRetentionPeriod
_Layout.cshtml: Adding a JS script that includes "builder.withServerTimeout(7200000)"

Is there a way to fix this? Or, did we develop using the wrong technology?
Thanks in advance.

The user often starts to enter some info (often, quite a lot of info) in a form, gets pulled onto some other issue and then comes back to find the server has disconnected; May I know how much data is sent via the form? If the default limit of signalr is exceeded, you can try to modify MaximumReceiveMessageSize.

For this requirement(The client would like to have the connection remain active for at least 2 hours from the last UI activity), we can add custom heartbeat monitoring, it can keep the connections alive.

The following code can solve the Could not reconnect to the server. Reload the page to restore functionality. issue in the screenshot below. I made a preliminary calculation and it might take 10 seconds for recovering automatically.

Here is my test code
_Host.cshtml  (autostart="false" is important, please check all the comments carefully)
@page "/"
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web
@namespace BlazorApp2.Pages
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <base href="~/" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link href="css/site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="BlazorApp2.styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png"/>
    <component type="typeof(HeadOutlet)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />
</head>
<body>
    <component type="typeof(App)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />

    <div id="blazor-error-ui">
        <environment include="Staging,Production">
            An error has occurred. This application may no longer respond until reloaded.
        </environment>
        <environment include="Development">
            An unhandled exception has occurred. See browser dev tools for details.
        </environment>
        <a href="" class="reload">Reload</a>
        <a class="dismiss"></a>
    </div>
    @*  autostart="false" here *@
    <script src="_framework/blazor.server.js" autostart="false"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/microsoft-signalr/6.0.0/signalr.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        // connect heartbeatHub
        const connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
            .withUrl("/heartbeatHub")
            .build();

        connection.start().then(() => {
            console.log("Connected to heartbeatHub");

            setInterval(() => {
                connection.invoke("SendHeartbeat")
                    .then(() => console.log("Heartbeat sent"))
                    .catch(err => console.error(err.toString()));
            }, 5 * 60 * 1000); // Every 5 minutes will sent a Heartbeat
        }).catch(err => console.error(err.toString()));

        connection.on("HeartbeatReceived", (message) => {
            console.log(`Server response: ${message}`);
        });
        connection.onclose(async () => {
            console.log("Connection closed, retrying...");
            await connection.start();
        });
        // For reconnecting the _blazor default hub
        Blazor.start().then(() => {
            Object.defineProperty(Blazor.defaultReconnectionHandler, '_reconnectionDisplay', {
                get() {
                    return this.__reconnectionDisplay;
                },
                set(value) {
                    this.__reconnectionDisplay = {
                        show: () => value.show(),
                        update: (d) => value.update(d),
                        rejected: (d) => document.location.reload()
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>

HeartbeatHub.cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;

namespace BlazorApp2
{
    public class HeartbeatHub : Hub
    {
        public async Task SendHeartbeat()
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Received heartbeat from {Context.ConnectionId} at {DateTime.UtcNow}");

            await Clients.Caller.SendAsync("HeartbeatReceived", "pong");
        }
    }
}

Program.cs
using BlazorApp2;
using BlazorApp2.Data;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<WeatherForecastService>();
// [Optional] The second steps to check the size of your data in the form
builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor().AddHubOptions(options =>
{
    options.MaximumReceiveMessageSize = 1024 * 1024; // Set Size = 1MB
});

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();
// Register HeartbeatHub
app.MapHub<HeartbeatHub>("/heartbeatHub");

app.MapBlazorHub();
app.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");

app.Run();


Hi Jason. Thanks for your great responses. Wow! I was hoping for a setting somewhere. I will give this code a try (after I try to understand it) and let you know how it performed. Thanks again.

Unfortunately, this did not help. Argh! Should have spent the extra bit of time to create an API and used WASM.
